# why do I get wrong lengths of a columns read from CSV file, python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to read some data (genome names) from a '.csv' file, I want to find the length of each column and afterwards build a barchart with these data but somehow my script shows that all columns have the same length which is not true. I have 4 columns in my file and in each cell of the  column is a genome name. The wrong number of columns is afterwards also represented in the '.png' file. I deleted ever '0' value and in my file but still the issue is not gone. This is my code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ca1 = []
casU3 =[]
casU5 =[]
casBig = []
df = pd.read_csv('statistics.csv')
ca1 = df['1 cassette']
casU3 = df['2-3 cassettes']
casU5 = df['4-5 cassettes']
casBig = df['More then 5 cassettes']
cas1 = len(list(filter(None, ca1)))
casUntil3 = len(list(filter(None, casU3)))
casUntil5 = len(list(filter(None, casU5)))
Bigcas = len(list(filter(None, casBig)))
genomes = cas1 + casUntil3 + casUntil5 + Bigcas
height = [cas1,casUntil3,casUntil5,Bigcas]
bars = ('No.of genomes with only 1 cassette','2-3 cassettes','4-5 cassettes','more than 5 cassettes')
y_pos = np.arange(len(bars))
plt.bar(y_pos, height, tick_label = bars, width = 0.5, color=(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1),  edgecolor='blue')
plt.ylabel('Number of genomes') 
plt.title('Statistics over %s genomes with CRISPR immune system' %genomes) 
plt.savefig('./histogramCRISPR.png')
plt.show()
```

The code is short and easy but somehow I can't find the issue. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to have not equal columns, either the columns will have NaN values or some or the other values.

please check for NaN values.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you but I did  and nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

It is incomprehensible to have not rise to columns, either the columns will have NaN values or a few or the other values. Drop the Nan values with the code:

```
df.drop.isna()
```

You can see the NaNs which is code:

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

`